# How to call Rscript from R?

Tags: r, testing, rscript

I am developing a package that exposes an R interface (a bunch of functions to be used interactively) and a command line interface via Rscript. This second one works via a small launcher, for instance, at the command line:

```
Rscript mylauncher.R arg1 arg2 arg3
```

would call a function of my package.
I would like to test a couple of command lines from R. Nothing fancy, just make sure that everything runs without errors.
If I test these calls doing in an R source file:

```
system("Rscript mylauncher.R arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

How can I be sure that I called the right Rscript? In case there are multiple R installations? (which is actually the case in my setting).
Another approach would be write in the R source file:

```
source("mylauncher.R")
```

But I don't see how to specify the command line (I would avoid the trick of overwriting the function `commandArgs`, because I want to test also the right tokenization of the command line). Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that "you can call R from R"?  In other words, you have not explained why you need to out to `Rscript` when you already are in R.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I believe that I explained it "I would like to test a couple of command lines from R", i.e. I want to test if some commands written in a unix terminal lead to an error, and this error is not due to the wrong version of Rscript being called.

Comment: maybe (on a Unix system) `system("which Rscript")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding

> How can I be sure that I called the right Rscript? In case there are
>   multiple R installations?

you would query `R RHOME` on the command-line and `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` from wihthin R.

You then append `bin/RScript` and should have the `Rscript` corresponding to your current session.  I still design my libraries in such a way that I can call them from R ...